# Electron dialog object not return anything, says Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, desktop

I am trying to implement I/O Operations on this tutorial App I am building. Everything else is working correctly, the only problem I am having is that the application does not console.log() the desired result, which is supposed to be the location of the selected file in the dialog box.

Here is a Screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: You gotta share your code here brother. The screenshots don't help us. also, what you are doing is probably an async operation, so you need to wait for promise to resolve before accessing the chosen files. probably your code should be something like `dialog.showOpenDialog(...).then(files=>{ // do your work here })`

Comment: Here is the link to the code, https://github.com/williammabotja/Electron-Codes/blob/master/main.js

Comment: Guys, I'm having trouble reading the contents of the files, I've tried everything, But I've managed to catch the promise, the application is working but the contents of a file cannot be retrieved. How do I make sure that dialog.showOpenDialog returns data that can be accessed  as a string buffer?

Comment: you need to use a FileReader. specifically, `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`. you can read more here, just google examples of reading file inputs in web and its the same thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As r3wt said, when you see `promise<pending>`, it means you have not properly awaited the return of an async function. Try changing your getFileFromUser function to be async, like this:

```
const getFileFromUser = async () => {

    // Triggers the OS' Open File Dialog box. We also pass it as a Javascript
    // object of different configuration arguments to the function

    //This operation is asynchronous and needs to be awaited
    const files = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
        // The Configuration object sets different properties on the Open File Dialog 
        properties: ['openFile']
    });

    // If we don't have any files, return early from the function
    if (!files) {
        return;
    }

    // Pulls the first file out of the array

    //const file = files[0];
    // Reads from the file and converts the resulting buffer to a string
    //const content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();

    // Log the Files to the Console
    console.log(files)
}
```