# Jquery firing too soon in Node with Promise.all

Tags: jquery, node.js, async-await, promise, electron

I have some async code in Electron and Node which runs in a Jquery each loop and then reacts once completed:

```js
$(async() => {
  if (await window.electronAPI.delete_items(project.name)) {
    var _count = 0;
    $.each(project.items, function(i, item) {
      var promises = item.subitems.map(async function(subitem) {
        return await window.electronAPI.update_item(subitem);
      });

      Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        _count++;
        if (_count >= project.items.length) {
          $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
          console.log("Done");
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

All of this works fine, however:

```
$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

runs immediately, whereas:

```
console.log( "Done" );
```

correctly runs after all the items have been updated.

What do I need to do to prevent the JQuery from running too early?

Thanks :)

Edit to add full code:

```js
index.js
--------------------------------------

app.whenReady().then( () => {

  ...

    ipcMain.handle( "delete_all_cached_images", delete_all_cached_images );
    ipcMain.handle( "update_cached_image", update_cached_image );

    /* Create the window */
    createWindow();

    app.on( "activate", () => {
        
        /* Fix MacOS multi window bug */
        if( BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0 ) createWindow();
    } );
} );

async function update_cached_image( e, project_name, image_type, image_size, image_name, image_data ) {

    /* Create a new blank image */
    let image = new Jimp( image_size, image_size, function ( err, image ) {
        
        if( err )
            return false;

        /* Map the pixels correct */
        var _image_data = Array.from( { length: image_size }, () => Array.from( { length: image_size }, () => undefined ) );

        for( var row_sel = 0; row_sel < image_size; row_sel++ )
            for( var col_sel = 0; col_sel < image_size; col_sel++ )
                _image_data[ col_sel ][ row_sel ]  = image_data.data[ row_sel ][ col_sel ];

        /* Loop through each pixel to add to the image */
        _image_data.forEach( ( row, y ) => {

            row.forEach( ( colour, x ) => {

                /* If we have a transparent pixel, don't add it to the image */
                if( ( colour == "" ) || ( colour == null ) )
                    image.setPixelColor( Jimp.rgbaToInt( 0, 0, 0, 0 ), parseInt( x ), parseInt( y ) );
                else 
                    image.setPixelColor( Jimp.cssColorToHex( "#" + colour ), parseInt( x ), parseInt( y ) );
            } );
        } );

        /* Resize to a nice large size */
        image.resize( 512, 512 , Jimp.RESIZE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR );

        /* Save the image to project directory */
        image.write( path.join(  __dirname, "projects", project_name, "cache", image_type, image_name + ".png" ), ( err ) => {
        
            if( err )
                return false;
        } );
    } );

    return true;
}

preload.js
--------------------------------------
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require( "electron" );

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld( "electronAPI", {

    ...

    delete_all_cached_images: ( project_name ) => ipcRenderer.invoke( "delete_all_cached_images", project_name ),
    update_cached_image: ( project_name, image_type, image_size, image_name, image_data ) => ipcRenderer.invoke( "update_cached_image", project_name, image_type, image_size, image_name, image_data )
} );

renderer.js
--------------------------------------
function update_cached_images() {

    $( async () => {

        /* First delete all old cached images */
        if( await window.electronAPI.delete_all_cached_images( project.name ) ) {


            var ti = 0;
            Promise.all( project.textures.map( g_texture => {
                
                return Promise.all( g_texture.textures.map( texture => {

                    return window.electronAPI.update_cached_image( project.name, "textures", 8, ( g_texture.name + "_" + ti++ ), texture );
                } ) );
            } ) ).then( () => {
                
                $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
                console.log("Done");
            } ).catch(err => {

                console.log(err);
                // add something to handle/process errors here
            } );
            
        } else {

            show_error( "Error caching project textures." );
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: `return await window.electronAPI.update_item(subitem);` shouldn't have `await`. You want to return the promises so you can put them in the array that `Promise.all()` will wait for.

Comment: What runs too early?  What do you want it to wait for?  You have two nested loops a `$.each()` with a `.map()` inside the `$.each()`.  So, are you trying to wait for ALL loops to be done?  Or trying to run something at the end of each `$.each()` iteration?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes that's right, it loops through groups of items and each item group has a load of sub items too. So once both loops are complete, the console.log functions fires exactly as expcted. But the JQuery function fire immediately for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar even with await, the promise* is (from the outside perspective) immediately returned because the function is async. (*: an equivalent one, actually, but that doesn't matter) Am I missing something?

Comment: @GSephElec What you describe doesn't make sense to me. Did you verify it by setting breakpoints on the statements? You can also set a DOM breakpoint on the element to see if anything _else_ is modifying it first.

Comment: @CherryDT weirdly it works fine in the debugger, the `$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );` function calls at the same time as `console.log( "Done" );` function. But if I try again outside of the debugger, they don't fire at the same time, there is a noticeable gap between the two. If I remove `$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );`, then the `#overlay` element, never goes away, so there's definitely nothing else interferring.

Comment: It's odd that this would happen but maybe hiding that div causes an expensive blocking rerender or something of the sort, try logging `Date.now()` before and after the call and check for the difference amount in milliseconds

Comment: @jfriend00 No because there is the `_count` which will make it fire only the last time.

Comment: This code can be written a LOT cleaner.  But, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish or what the current problem is.  When do you want `$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );` to run?  You have an N x M loop and a counter that is counting N.

Comment: Yeah and that counter is a hack for poorly written code.  This can be written so much cleaner.   So, you just want to call `$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );` when the last N x M loop is done?

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't have a lot of experience with Node tbh. I basically need these loops to run, calling functions outside of the renderer of Electron and then once all the functions have been called, hide an overlay, that way I can show a "Loading" div whilst things are being done in the background.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the counter and just properly wait for all the promises to be done before calling `$( "#overlay" ).css( "display", "none" );` like this:

```
$(async () => {
    if (await window.electronAPI.delete_items(project.name)) {
        Promise.all(project.items.map(item => {
            return Promise.all(item.subitems.map(subitem => {
                return window.electronAPI.update_item(subitem);
            }));
        })).then(() => {
            $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
            console.log("Done");
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            // add something to handle/process errors here
        });
    }
});
```

This, of course, assumes that `window.electronAPI.update_item(subitem);` returns a promise that properly resolves only when it's done.  If it doesn't return a promise or if the promise doens't resolve only when its done, then we'll have to fix that too.

Here's is a fixed up version of `update_cached_image()` that returns a promise that resolves when it is done:

```
function update_cached_image(e, project_name, image_type, image_size, image_name, image_data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        /* Create a new blank image */
        new Jimp(image_size, image_size, function(err, image) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            /* Map the pixels correct */
            var _image_data = Array.from({ length: image_size }, () => Array.from({ length: image_size }, () => undefined));

            for (var row_sel = 0; row_sel < image_size; row_sel++)
                for (var col_sel = 0; col_sel < image_size; col_sel++)
                    _image_data[col_sel][row_sel] = image_data.data[row_sel][col_sel];

            /* Loop through each pixel to add to the image */
            _image_data.forEach((row, y) => {

                row.forEach((colour, x) => {

                    /* If we have a transparent pixel, don't add it to the image */
                    if ((colour == "") || (colour == null))
                        image.setPixelColor(Jimp.rgbaToInt(0, 0, 0, 0), parseInt(x), parseInt(y));
                    else
                        image.setPixelColor(Jimp.cssColorToHex("#" + colour), parseInt(x), parseInt(y));
                });
            });

            /* Resize to a nice large size */
            image.resize(512, 512, Jimp.RESIZE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);

            /* Save the image to project directory */
            image.write(path.join(__dirname, "projects", project_name, "cache", image_type, image_name + ".png"), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    resolve(image);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant, thank you. But I'm still having the same issue, the `#overlay` div is hidden immediately and then after a few seconds, the `console.log` function fires.

Comment: @GSephElec - Then, apparently, `update_item()` isn't returning a promise properly that resolves when its done.  I don't know electron - can you point to a reference page for that API?

Comment: if it helps, here's a video of what happens: https://imgur.com/a/AVa8Zs5

Comment: it's from the ipcRenderer module: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args

Comment: @GSephElec - I don't see any code for an `.update_item()` method in that ipcRenderer link.  I need to know exactly what that function does (see its code or see its doc).  It appears you think it returns a promise that resolves when its done with whatever it does, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: it doesn't return any promises, it just returns true or false. I could post the code but it wouldn't show anything except either a `return true` or `return false` statement. I followed the information for `ipcRenderer.invoke` as found here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way and then followed the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272351/electron-dialog-object-not-return-anything-says-promise-pending) regarding promises. I believe Electron returns the promise, not anything I write in my main.js function.

Comment: @GSephElec - Well, then the problem is that `.update_item()` does not communicate back to its caller when its done.  So, there is NOTHING the caller can do about that.  It simply  doesn't know when the underlying operation is done.  If you show us what `update_item()` does (show us that code and any code that it calls), then perhaps we can advise further.  We've done everything we can do on this end.  Now, we need to fix `.update_item()`.

Comment: updated post to include full code snippets

Comment: @GSephElec - If I follow what you added to you're question, you're calling `udpate_cached_image()` which was immediately returning a boolean (without waiting for the asynchronous operations to complete).  I've added a fixed up version of that function that returns a promise that resolves/rejects when the asynchronous operations in it are done.

Comment: it's looking a lot more promising, thank you :) but node is returning the error:
> Error occurred in handler for 'update_cached_image': Error: An object could not be cloned.
>    at on.e._reply (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:11226)
>    at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:544

Comment: @GSephElec - OK, you're getting an error somewhere.  Time to do some debugging to figure out why, right?